# Group BY based on one column and get unique and sum of other columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have dataframe like this:

```
id   product   department   price
1      x           a          5
2      y           b         10
1      z           b         15
3      z           a         2
2      x           a         1
1      x           a         1
4      w           b         10
```

Now I want to groupby using `id` and get all unique value of `product and department` in list associated with it and sum of price.

Expected Output:

```
id   product   department   price
1    [x, z]      [a, b]      21
2    [x, y]      [a, b]      11
3    [z]         [a]         2
4    [w]         [b]         10
```

Now I can do groupby and get one column from 3, but I'm not able to figure out how to get all three.

```
df.groupby(['id'])[product].unique()
```

Answer (score 1):

Groupby on `id`, apply the required aggregates on the columns. For unique values, one way to do is `list(set(<sequence>))` if order is not needed to be preserved. If you need the order, then you can use `x.unique().tolist()` instead of `list(set(x))`

```py
out = (df.groupby('id')
      .agg({'product': lambda x: list(set(x)),
            'department': lambda x: list(set(x)),
            'price': sum
            })
       )
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
   product department  price
id                          
1   [z, x]     [a, b]     21
2   [x, y]     [a, b]     11
3      [z]        [a]      2
4      [w]        [b]     10
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple case of using `agg()` with a **dict** definition

```
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""id   product   department   price
1      x           a          5
2      y           b         10
1      z           b         15
3      z           a         2
2      x           a         1
1      x           a         1
4      w           b         10"""), sep="\s+")

df.groupby("id").agg({"price":"sum","product":lambda s: s.unique().tolist(), "department":lambda s: s.unique().tolist()})
```

| id | price | product | department |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 | ['x', 'z'] | ['a', 'b'] |
| 2 | 11 | ['y', 'x'] | ['b', 'a'] |
| 3 | 2 | ['z'] | ['a'] |
| 4 | 10 | ['w'] | ['b'] |

Answer (score 1):

To get **sorted list** of unique values of `product` and `department` (as shown on your expected result), you can use [`np.unique()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) together with [`GroupBy.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html), as follows:

```
import numpy as np

df.groupby('id', as_index=False).agg(
    {'product': lambda x: np.unique(x).tolist(), 
     'department': lambda x: np.unique(x).tolist(), 
     'price': 'sum'})
```

**Result:**

```
   id product department  price
0   1  [x, z]     [a, b]     21
1   2  [x, y]     [a, b]     11
2   3     [z]        [a]      2
3   4     [w]        [b]     10
```